# TypeError: Object.key is read-only

Tags: reactjs, crud

guys. I'm trying to implement Edit functionality on my invoice app, I pass invoice as props to form state like this :

```
const EditInvoice = ({invoice}) => {
  const [formInputs, setFormInputs] = useState([
  ]);
  const [form,setForm] = useState({
      clientCity : invoice.clientAddress.city,
      clientCountry : invoice.clientAddress.country,
      clientPostCode : invoice.clientAddress.postCode,
      clientStreet : invoice.clientAddress.street,
    clientEmail : invoice.clientEmail,
    clientName : invoice.clientName,
    createdAt : invoice.createdAt,
    description : invoice.description,
    id : invoice.id,
    items: formInputs,
    paymentDue : invoice.paymentDue,
    paymentTerms : invoice.paymentTerms,
      senderCity : invoice.senderAddress.city,
      senderCountry : invoice.senderAddress.country,
      senderPostCode : invoice.senderAddress.postCode,
      senderStreet : invoice.senderAddress.street,
    status : invoice.status,
    total : invoice.total
  })
```

At this point everything works, handleChange function works for everything except for formInputs, i tried setting formInputs state like this
`const [formInputs, setFormInputs] = useState([...invoice.items]);` and using useEffect, like this :

```
useEffect(() =>{
    setFormInputs([...invoice.items])
  },[])
```

And they both populate the fields, but if I try updating my invoice items array I get read-only type error, just in case, here's what I used for my handleChange function

```
const handleItemChange = (index,e) =>{
    const values = [...formInputs]
    values[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    values[index].total = (values[index].price * values[index].quantity).toFixed(2);
    setFormInputs(values)
  }
```

Hoping you guys could provide me with solution, Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's a hacky way to do it, but this solution seems to work.

```
useEffect(() =>{
    invoice.items.map(item => setFormInputs(prevState => ([...prevState, {
      id : item.id,
      name : item.name,
      quantity : item.quantity,
      price : item.price,
      total : item.total
    }])))
    console.log(formInputs);
  },[])
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your code is that your are trying to re-assign a `const` value that is **read-only** (it prevents the re-assignment). Define your values as `let`.

So instead of

```
const values
```

you should define it as

```
let values
```

Comment: I just tried it, doesn't change anything, I have a function where I can add more objects into that array, 
```
<Button
            onClick={() =>
              setFormInputs((prevState) => [
                ...prevState,
                { id: uuidv4(), name : "", quantity : 0, price: 0, total : 0 },
              ])
            }}
```
The added objects can be updated no problem. This same exact code was used when I initally created invoice as well.

Comment: The problem is surely in the variable inside the `handleItemChange`. Now I look better your code to see if I find other problems